# How does a C++ std::mutex bind to a resource?

Tags: c++, concurrency, locking, mutex

Does the compiler simply check which variables are being modified between the lock and unlock statements and bind them to the mutex so there is exclusive access to them?

Or does a `mutex.lock()` lock all resources which are visible in the current scope?

Comment: the mutex doesn't lock any variables, it merely blocks a thread that's trying to acquire it. This has the effect of protecting variables if the program only accesses them between a `lock()` and `unlock()` call. The presence of the mutex `lock()` and `unlock()` in the code also prevents the compiler from re-ordering memory access of variable *accesses* thus protected.

Comment: You also need to make sure that the threads use the same mutex object. Having a different mutex in each thread will do nothing. Instead it blocks if another thread tries to lock an already locked mutex like @RichardHodges described.

Comment: Thanks, that really cleared it!

Answer (score 19, accepted):

Given that `m` is a variable of type `std::mutex`:

Imagine this sequence:

```
int a;
m.lock();
b += 1;
a = b;
m.unlock();
do_something_with(a);
```

There is an 'obvious' thing going on here:

The assignment of a from b and the increment of b is 'protected' from interference from other threads, because other threads will attempt to lock the same `m` and will be blocked until we call `m.unlock()`.

**And there is a more subtle thing going on.**

In single-threaded code, the compiler will seek to re-order loads and stores. Without the locks, the compiler would be free to effectively re-write your code if this turned out to be more efficient on your chipset:

```
int a = b + 1;
//    m.lock();
b = a;
//    m.unlock();
do_something_with(a);
```

Or even:

```
do_something_with(++b);
```

However, `std::mutex::lock()`, `unlock()`, `std::thread()`, `std::async()`, `std::future::get()` and so on are *fences*. The compiler 'knows' that it may not reorder loads and stores (reads and writes) in such a way that the operation ends up on the other side of the fence from where you specified when you wrote the code.

```
1:
2:    m.lock(); <--- This is a fence
3:    b += 1;   <--- So this load/store operation may not move above line 2
4:    m.unlock(); <-- Nor may it be moved below this line
```

Imagine what would happen if this wasn't the case:

(Reordered code)

```
thread1: int a = b + 1;
  <--- Here another thread precedes us and executes the same block of code
  thread2: int a = b + 1;
  thread2: m.lock();
  thread2: b = a;
  thread2: m.unlock();
thread1: m.lock();
thread1: b = a;
thread1: m.unlock();
thread1:do_something_with(a);
thread2:do_something_with(a);
```

If you follow it through, you'll see that b now has the wrong value in it, because the compiler was tying to make your code faster.

...and that's only the compiler optimisations. `std::mutex`, etc. also prevents the memory caches from reordering loads and stores in a more 'optimal' way, which would be fine in a single-threaded environment but disastrous in a multi-core (i.e. any modern PC or phone) system.

There is a cost for this safety, because thread A's cache must be flushed before thread B reads the same data, and flushing caches to memory is hideously slow compared to cached memory access. But c'est la vie. It's the only way to make concurrent execution safe.

This is why we prefer that, if possible, in an SMP system, each thread has its own copy of data on which to work. We want to minimise not only the time spent in a lock, but also the number of times we cross a fence.

I could go on to talk about the `std::memory_order` modifiers, but that is a dark and dangerous hole, which experts often get wrong and in which beginners have no hope of getting it right.

Comment: Your last sentence is an understatement. :)

Comment: Excellent "potential rewrite" example!

Answer (score 7):

"mutex" is short for "mutual exclusion"; the proper discipline for using a mutex is to lock it before entering any code that modifies variables that are shared between threads and to unlock it when that section of code is done. If one thread locks the mutex, any other thread that tries to lock it will be blocked until the thread that owns the mutex unlocks it. That means that only one thread at a time is inside code that can modify the shared variables, and that eliminates race conditions.

The rest of what a mutex does relies on compiler magic at some level: it also prevents the compiler from moving loads and stores of data from inside the protected code to outside it, and vice versa, which is necessary for the protected code to stay protected.

Answer (score 5):

There's no such cleverness at all, and making it work correctly is the programmer's responsibility.

A mutex is like a lockable door on a house that has no walls.

All you can do with it is prevent others from entering the house *through the door* when it's locked.
The door is only useful if everyone agrees to exclusively enter the house through the door, and that when the door is locked wait for the person inside to unlock the door and exit.
Nothing prohibits a bad person from entering the house through the non-existent walls except the agreement that you shouldn't.

Comment: the cleverness is in the fact that the compiler's optimiser and code generator recognise and respect the implied memory fences.

Comment: Never mind that without walls you don't have very much of a house.

Comment: Let's say that we have a global variable `a`. I have a function `f` that does something like this - `std:: mutex m; while(true) {a++; }`. 

I launch the function `f` in a new thread. Will any other function be able to read or write `a`?

Comment: Very sad limitation of C++. See Rust's https://doc.rust-lang.org/std/sync/struct.Mutex.html, a completely generic mutex with walls AND doors.

Answer (score 4):

A mutex is a particular implementation of a [semaphore](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Semaphore_(programming)). In particular it's a *binary* semaphore.

A semaphore (obviously in a computer science context) can be implemented as a integer variable and hardware or software (operative system) *primitive* which are *atomic* (cannot be interrupted).

Imagine something *like*  (pseudo-hight level code):

```
int mutex = 1;  // The mutex is free when created (free=1, occupied=0).

// in a concurrency block
{
  :try-again

  // test if mutex is 1 (is free).
  if (mutex > 0) {

    // mutex WAS free so now I set as occupied (set 0)
    --mutex;
    // Now I've 'acquired' the mutex and since the mutex is 0 or 1
    // only me can be here.

    // Do something in mutual exclusion
    // Done.
    // Unlock the mutex
    ++mutex;
    // Now the mutex is free so other threads can acquire it.

  } else {
    // Mutex is 0 so I tried but it's already occupied.
    // Block the thread and try again.
    goto try-again;
  }

}
```

Obvious in a pure high-level language, that approach cannot work because a thread could be interrupted after it has tested the mutex is free and before it can set as occupied.

For that reason the semaphores and so mutex are implemented with the aid of primitive instructions which implement those "test and set" operation in "one clock" (atomically).

An example is the [`test-and-set`](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Test-and-set) primitive.

Comment: Because I've been burned by treating mutex and binary semaphore as interchangable, there is a difference.  In many threading libraries (such as pthreads), a mutex may only be unlocked by the thread that locked it, while a semaphore can be "unlocked" by any thread.

Answer (score 1):

In terms of resource usage, the compiler couldn't care less about `mutex.lock()`. It is programmers duty to ensure that resource access is happening within proper locking/unlocking.

However, the compiler cares about a mutex in a way that it knows not to optimize away certain constructs which it would otherwise - but you are probably not interested in this right now.